# How to transform a Set into an Array with commas after each element without allocating new memory in kotlin?

Tags: arrays, kotlin, optimization, mapping

The scenario is the following:

```
fun scenario(names:Set<String>){
log( /here comes the transformed set );
}
```

It is important to mention that log receives a varargs type of parameter of type object.

What I tried is the following: *names.toTypeArray().

The problem with this is that, besides allocating new space for the new list, it also misses the required commas

What I want to achieve is something like: log("John", "," , "John", etc...) at runtime.

Comment: What do you mean by "it also misses the required commas"? Can you show what it actually produced so that I can compare it to what you want to achieve? And also, please show a [mcve].

Comment: To answer the second part of your question, no, you cannot do this without allocating new space. Do you realise that even calling a varargs function "normally", like `log(a, b, c)` allocates a new array?

Comment: I will change the description to showcase better what I need.

Comment: The problem is not about the varargs function, I need a way of mapping the set without allocating a new array for it

Comment: You mean you want to insert strings that are just a single comma, `","`, in between elements of the set? If so, please [edit] your question.

Comment: Are you sure you don't want to just *join* all the strings together into one single string, with commas as the separator?

Comment: Just use `log(set.joinToString())`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this.

```
val arr :Array<String> = (names.chunked(1) // Chunking set into 1 element lists
    .flatMap { it.plus(",") } // Adding comma next to each elements and flatten the list
    .toList() as ArrayList) // Type casting to arraylist
    .also { it.removeLast() } //Removing comma after last element
    .toTypedArray() // Converting to array
someFun(*arr) // Passing array as vararg
```

One thing to remember here if you want to maintain order of insertion, names set should be [LinkedHashSet](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/-linked-hash-set/) .As order sets like TreeSet, HashSet.. does not maintain the order.

```
fun someFun(vararg a: String) {
    a.forEach {
        print(it)
    }
}
```

**Note:** This is only an idiomatic solution. Even though we dont use extra space here,it internally does creating extra space.

Hope it helps. [Link to Kotlin Playground.](https://pl.kotl.in/DJ0hKP2yh)